Connect negative reference of DAC to ground?
I am currently looking for a >16Bit DAC and will probably use the AD5781. To obtain a bipolar output voltage, you can either use a negative reference voltage or operate in X2 gain mode. My question refers to the example circuit of this mode. (See image)

I can't figure out why the negative reference voltage input is not simply connected directly to ground, but is driven to 0V via an opamp instead.

Isn't it just an additional inaccuracy due to the offset voltage?
Is the only purpose to create a symmetrical circuit?
Would there be a disadvantage of using the second OPV of the AD8676 for the output amplifier (rather than for the negative reference)?

